# Compressing a sentence into ascii and then decompressing it back

Tags: python-3.x, ascii

When I'm trying to compress this sentence into the ASCII equivalent, I keep getting this error code `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 5 found`

How can I fix the following code

```
def menu():
    print("Compress a file                            Press 1")
    print("Decompress a file                          Press 2")
    print("Quit                                       Press 3")
    user_choice = input("")
    if user_choice=="1":
        compressing()
    elif user_choice=="2":
        decompressing()
    elif user_choice=="3":
        import sys
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Input invalid.Please enter a number for path selection") , "\n" , menu()

def compressing():
    compressed_sentence=[]
    sentence=input("Enter a sentence: ")
    sentence=sentence.split()
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        character=(sentence[i])
        ascii_character=ord(character)
        compressed_sentence.append(ascii_character)
    with open('compressed_file.txt','w') as myFile:
        myFile.write(str(compressed_sentence))
    menu()

def decompressing():
    with open('compressed_file.txt','r') as myFile:
        sentence=myFile.read()
    for i in sentence:
        if i in "[],'":
            sentence=sentence.replace(i," ")
    new_sentence=sentence.split()
    decompressed_sentence=str("")
    for i in range(len(new_sentence)):
        character=int(new_sentence[i])
        decompressed_sentence=(decompressed_sentence+(chr(character)))
    final_decompressed_sentence=decompressed_sentence.split()
    print(final_decompressed_sentence)
    with open('decompressed_file.txt','w') as myFile:
        myFile.write(final_decompressed_sentence)
    menu()

menu()
```

in order for it to be able to compress and decompress it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Its okay i got it working:

```
def menu():
    print("Create a file                              Press 1")
    print("Compress a file                            Press 2")
    print("Decompress a file                          Press 3")
    print("Quit                                       Press 4")
    user_choice = input("")
    if user_choice=="1":
        create_a_file()
    elif user_choice=="2":
        compressing()
    elif user_choice=="3":
        decompressing()
    elif user_choice=="4":
        import sys
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Input invalid.Please enter a number for path selection") , "\n" , menu()

def create_a_file():
    sentence=input("Enter a sentence: ")
    sentence=sentence.split()
    with open('file.txt','w') as myFile:
        myFile.write(str(sentence))
    menu()

def compressing():
    compressed_sentence=[]
    with open('file.txt','r') as myFile:
        sentence=myFile.read()
    for i in sentence:
        if i in "[],'":
            sentence=sentence.replace(i," ")
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        character=(sentence[i])
        ascii_character=ord(character)
        compressed_sentence.append(ascii_character)
    with open('compressed_file.txt','w') as myFile:
        myFile.write(str(compressed_sentence))
    menu()

def decompressing():
    with open('compressed_file.txt','r') as myFile:
        sentence=myFile.read()
    for i in sentence:
        if i in "[],'":
            sentence=sentence.replace(i," ")
    new_sentence=sentence.split()
    decompressed_sentence=str("")
    for i in range(len(new_sentence)):
        character=int(new_sentence[i])
        decompressed_sentence=(decompressed_sentence+(chr(character)))
    final_decompressed_sentence=decompressed_sentence.split()
    print(final_decompressed_sentence)
    menu()

menu()
```